# Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, build.gradle

I have problems about the NDK-Build. That is the failure message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'ndk-build.cmd''
```

I has testing some fixes, but it doesn't working. I don't know what i can do more. I hope you can help to fixing my problem:

Here is the build.gradle:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
     compileSdkVersion 14
     buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "teaonly.droideye"
    targetSdkVersion 14

    ndk {
        moduleName "MediaEncoder"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

sourceSets.main {
    jni.srcDirs = [] // This prevents the auto generation of Android.mk
    jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
}

//Call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main/jniLibs').absolutePath
    } else {
        commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main/jniLibs').absolutePath
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}

}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/java_websocket.jar')
}
```

And this is my local.properties:

```
ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Markus\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Markus\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

Here is my Project:

[Project Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aObZb.png)

Comment: You can use the built-in [C++ support](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html) in Android Studio, no need to define your own **ndkBuild** task anymore.

Comment: i know, but this isn't my own projetct.

Comment: If you prefer not to touch the files, make sure that `C:\Users\Markus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle` is on PATH

Comment: I check it on the path and find the ndk-build.cmd

Comment: Try running `gradlew assembleRelease --debug` (or `--stacktrace`) and see if you can get some more detailed info about the error.

Comment: `'src/main/jniLibs'` doesn't look correct. Probably your **Android.mk** file is in `'src/main/jni`, then use `commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath`. But most likely, you must also set `jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/libs']`.

Comment: i try it, but they isn't more details about the error

Comment: @AlexCohn i make a picture about my project overview

Comment: In theory, with ndk-build you can achieve almost anything. But if you want an easy solution, rename your `jniLibs` directory to `jni` and apply the changes from my [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46134454/execution-failed-for-task-appndkbuild?noredirect=1#comment79246353_46134454).

Comment: I try it but it doesn't solve my problem. 

I change the order name to jni and change the commandline to 
_commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath_  
but i have still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that your not specifying the working directory for the Gradle task. Even though it set the ndk.dir setting correctly, the fact is that commandLine will default to the project directory, where there is no 'ndk-build.cmd' file. So, just add the following line to your task:

```
workingDir '/Users/Markus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle'
```

You can read more about this, and other Gradle options for commandLine, in the following location in the Gradle documentation:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i dont know in which line i need to add your line, please?

Comment: @MarkusJoos Just add the line immediately before the line that starts with `if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS))`